# Type '{ <S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>]; <S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefine

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

[image]

I got this error while I am writing dark mode for tailwind in react.
it says

Type '{ <S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>]; <S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefine

I am new to typescript, can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

I give some try after reading some documentation but didn't get the result.
const setTheme: DispatchString;
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Aman change useState{null} to useState(null)

Comment: is it necessary while using hooks function names also start from the capital letter, because react uses the camel case typography

Comment: in React yes.. because Capital starting of character shows react it as a component...

Comment: but it's not allowed to be useState to null because I'll use tailwind dark mode so need to update the "dark" keyword. So it's saying for a string I did it and it's working fine. but can you tell me how to do it with null?

Comment: simply pass "" inside useState... like useState("")